# Tryning to secure a front End react page with keycloak server but i have this error 'keycloak.init(...).then is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I'm trying to secure a react component with keycloak and so far i've done evrything as it told:

- I've installed the packages KEycloak via NPM
- I've put the keycloak.json in public folder
- I've modified my component so it would mount when page is routed

but at the end i get this error:

> keycloak.init(...).then is not a function

Ive tried to replace login-required by check-sso

here is my code injected in my component:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

componentDidMount() {
        const keycloak = Keycloak('./public/keycloak.json');
        keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
          this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })
        })
    }

render(){
    if (this.state.keycloak) {
        if (this.state.authenticated)
            return (<div className="container text-dark">);
        else return (<div>Unable to authenticate!</div>)
    }
    return (<div>Initializing Keycloak...</div>);
}
```

[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: Please include your error in text format directly in the question instead of linking to an external image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of :

`const keycloak = Keycloak('./public/keycloak.json');`

Try this:

`const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');`

and set **promiseType** to **native** in the init options like this(in your case) :

`keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required', promiseType: 'native'}).then(authenticated => {
   this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })
 })`

Answer (score 0):

Please check keycloak.json contains these values:-

```
{
    "realm": "...",
    "auth-server-url": "http://...",
    "ssl-required": "none",
    "resource": "...",
    "public-client": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Comment: this is my keycloak.json                                                                                                                        {
    "realm": "insapi",
    "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "simulgarantie",
    "public-client": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
  }

Comment: @Samar please check with `"ssl-required":"none"`  as auth-server-url is localhost and ssl certificate is not added

Comment: Still the same error, the function init isn't known i guess there 's an javascript adapter that i should be adding somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, but it's implemented with another library, but you can restrict React Routes / Component / Functions

Install @react-keycloak/web library

Pre requires: keycloak-js 9.0.2 or later

```
npm install --save keycloak-js
npm install --save @react-keycloak/web
```

Create a `keycloak.js` file in the `src` folder of your project with the following content to set up a Keycloak instance as needed.

Set up a Keycloak instance

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'
const keycloakConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth', 
  realm: 'Demo', 
  clientId: 'react-app'
}
const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
export default keycloak
```

Then Wrap your App inside `KeycloakProvider` and pass the `keycloak` instance as prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import keycloak from './keycloak'
import AppRouter from './routes'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <KeycloakProvider keycloak={keycloak}>
      <AppRouter/>
    </KeycloakProvider>
  )
}
```

As you see in AppRouter component `useKeycloak` is being used without 1st param because we don't need that keycloak instance object to be used. But 2nd `initialized` parameter is being used because `PrivateRoute` is using keycloak instance, and keycloak object need to be available on `PrivateRoute` initialization, that means until keycloak initialized Routes cannot be returned

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Menu from '../components/Menu';
import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../utilities/PrivateRoute';
import ProtectedPage from '../pages/ProtectedPage';


export const AppRouter = () => {
    const [, initialized] = useKeycloak();
    if (!initialized) {
        return <h3>Loading ... !!!</h3>;
    }
    return (<>
        <Menu />
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <PrivateRoute roles={['RealmAdmin']} path="/protected" component={ProtectedPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
    );
};
```

Create a `PrivateRoute.js` file in `src/utilities` folder of your project with the following content.

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


export function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, roles, ...rest }) {
  const [keycloak] = useKeycloak();

  const isAutherized = (roles) => {
    if (keycloak && roles) {
        return roles.some(r => {
            const realm =  keycloak.hasRealmRole(r);
            const resource = keycloak.hasResourceRole(r);
            return realm || resource;
        });
    }
    return false;
   }

   return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
            return isAutherized(roles)
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', }} />
        }}
      />
    )
}
```

Let’s see how to restrict Components/Functions with a Keycloak.

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';




    export default function AuthorizedFunction(roles) {
        const [keycloak, initialized] = useKeycloak();

        const isAutherized = () => {
            if (keycloak && roles) {
                return roles.some(r => {
                    const realm =  keycloak.hasRealmRole(r);
                    const resource = keycloak.hasResourceRole(r);
                    return realm || resource;
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        return isAutherized();
    }
```

[image]

Also, there is another way of restrict with anther wrapper component as below example. (with wrapper component)

https://medium.com/@cagline/authenticate-and-authorize-react-routes-component-with-keycloak-666e85662636

Comment: hi, one question about that, when I start using web app, clicking via urls from private router, before each page I see "Loading", how to change that ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Keycloak now uses .success() for a resolved promise and .error() for a rejected promise when keycloak.init() is triggered

```
const keycloak = Keycloak({
            "clientId": "...",
            "realm": "...",
            "url": "...",
            "ssl-required": "...",
          
            "credentials": {
                "secret": "...1"
            },
            "enable-cors": true,
            "public-client": true,
            "confidential-port": 0

        });
        keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(authenticated => {
            this.setState({ keycloak, authenticated: authenticated },loadData)
        })
```

Comment: It seems you are using an older version of Keycloak, `success` has been deprecated in favor of `then`. See the manual for reference: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing this out.. it's for an older version